# How to read in arguments passed via ant to testng.xml

Tags: xml, ant, shell, sh

Here is the scenario:

Have a **shell script** that calls **ant** with one argument. The ant in turn executes **testng.xml** (suite file) passing the same argument and testng in turn executes the **test** within passing the same argument.

In my case, I am passing the **browser string** eg.(firefox, iexplore) argument that will specify which browser test will run on. I want to be able to have my test result output tell me which browser the test run in.

I grab the argument from command line in ant by so:

...

```
<sysproperty key="browser" value="${browser}"/>
```

I was thinking that since ant calls testng.xml, i can do the same in testng.xml

I went to testng.xml and did something like:

```
<suite name="AcceptanceSuite_${browser}">
<test name="Acceptance Test_${browser}" >
```

I hope i didnt lose anybody. Not the best in explaining things but simply need away of capturing this argument in testng.xml and including that in the **suite name**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In build.xml file, set delegateCommandSystemProperties=true in testng tag and  add 
`<sysproperty key="property" value="${property}"/>` under testng tag as follows:

```
<target name="execute" depends="compile">
        <testng delegateCommandSystemProperties="true">
            <sysproperty key="property" value="${property}"/>
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
        </testng>
    </target>
```

In testng file add "key" and "value" in parameter tag as follows:

```
<parameter name="property" value="${property}"></parameter>
```

Run ant from command-line and pass parameter value as follows:

```
ant -Dproperty=true execute
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work with  `<sysproperty>` if you set [`delegateCommandSystemProperties`](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html) to `true` 
and nest the `<sysproperty>` within `<testng>`

Not sure if you have nested the `<sysproperty>` ?

Comment: hello can you please give an example of what you mean and where to include this option. Do you mean in the ant file (build.xml) or the suite file (testng.xml). How? Remember that i want to access this property in testng.xml file

Comment: see the link in my answer. this setting goes in testng.xml