# Setting System variable in ANT build tool and read it in Java using Syste.getEnv("ABC_HOME")

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, testng

I am running all testng test cases from Ant build tool . All configurations are done and I can run them via ANT tool and can generate reports. Now here is the problem:

While running all test  cases they read a environment variable using `System.getEnv("ABC_HOME")`. Now here all my test cases are either failing or either skipped because of failed config.

I saw multiple post but none of them works for me:

1. how to configure: http://testng.org/doc/ant.html
2. Setting the system variable:[How to read in arguments passed via ant to testng.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937817/how-to-read-in-arguments-passed-via-ant-to-testng-xml)
3. Controlling all testCases how to run them from ANT tool.
   [How do I control which tests to run in testng from ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915766/how-do-i-control-which-tests-to-run-in-testng-from-ant)
4. This link doesn't work: [How to set an env variable in Ant build.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701452/how-to-set-an-env-variable-in-ant-build-xml)

My configuration to set the System variable is as below. Please correct me if I am wrong:

```
   <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${unitTest.lib.dir}/testng.jar"/>


    <target name="runUnittests" depends="unitTestCompile">
      <property name="ABC_HOME" value="${base.dir}"/>
      <testng delegatecommandsystemproperties="true" classpathref="unitTest.classpath"
        outputDir="${testng.report.dir}" workingDir="${unitTest.src.dir}" haltOnfailure="true">
        <sysproperty key="property" value="${BLUEOPTIMA_HOME}"/>
        <xmlfileset dir="${unitTest.suites.dir}" includes="testng.xml"/>
      </testng>
    </target>
```

Every time my Java code look for variable ABC_HOME it's not able to find that environment variable and all test cases are failed or skipped. Setup using the env variable in ANT tool but none of them are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code, you should use [`System.getProperty("ABC_HOME")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) instead.

If you can't change the code, then you can do:

```
<target name="runUnittests" depends="unitTestCompile">
  <property name="ABC_HOME" value="${base.dir}"/>
  <testng fork="yes" delegatecommandsystemproperties="true" classpathref="unitTest.classpath"
    outputDir="${testng.report.dir}" workingDir="${unitTest.src.dir}" haltOnfailure="true">
    <env key="property" value="${BLUEOPTIMA_HOME}"/>
    <xmlfileset dir="${unitTest.suites.dir}" includes="testng.xml"/>
  </testng>
</target>
```

Comment: I can't change the code for UnitTesting .. is there a way I can set it as a environment variable ?

Comment: I really appreciate this but This solution doesn't work for me. Not sure why.

Comment: Sorry I got the problem. It works Thanks ! @juherr :)